# Fasest way to generate dictionaries from a pandas df without to_dict

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to go from this dataframe:

```
   run property  low  high  abs1perc0  in1out0  weight
0  bob        a    5     9          1        1       2
1  bob        s    5     9          1        1       2
2  bob        d    1    10          0        1       2
3  tom        a    1     2          1        1       2
4  tom        s    2     3          1        1       2
5  tom        d    8     9          0        1       2
```

to dictionaries that are named after a concatenation of the individual 'run' names and the column names (except property). Property has to become the key and the data has to become the values i.e:

```
boblow =       {'a':5, 's':5, 'd':1}
bobhigh =      {'a':9, 's':9, 'd':10}
bobabs1perc0 = {'a':1, 's':1, 'd':0}
...
tomlow =       {'a':1, 's':2, 'd':8}
...
```

This would have to happen to huge dfs and I cant wrap my head around how to do it other than by hand. I started making a list of concatenated names of individual values of the 'run' column but I'm certain someone here has a much faster and smarter way of doing it.

Thanks a Bunch!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend save the the output into `dict` of `dict` , also do not merge your `tuple` key to one key , also after we reshape your df, `to_dict` still work

```
d=df.set_index(['run','property']).stack().unstack(1).to_dict('index')
{('bob', 'low'): {'a': 5, 'd': 1, 's': 5}, ('bob', 'high'): {'a': 9, 'd': 10, 's': 9}, ('bob', 'abs1perc0'): {'a': 1, 'd': 0, 's': 1}, ('bob', 'in1out0'): {'a': 1, 'd': 1, 's': 1}, ('bob', 'weight'): {'a': 2, 'd': 2, 's': 2}, ('tom', 'low'): {'a': 1, 'd': 8, 's': 2}, ('tom', 'high'): {'a': 2, 'd': 9, 's': 3}, ('tom', 'abs1perc0'): {'a': 1, 'd': 0, 's': 1}, ('tom', 'in1out0'): {'a': 1, 'd': 1, 's': 1}, ('tom', 'weight'): {'a': 2, 'd': 2, 's': 2}}

d[('bob','low')]
{'a': 5, 'd': 1, 's': 5}
```

Comment: That's amazing, how do I call my dictionaries in this format though?

Comment: @tincanti like this d[('bob','low')]？